# PROC MEANS step in SAS: how to create variable out of mean and standard deviation?

Tags: sas

I'm running a simulation and need to link up the mean and standard deviation of two variables (e_2 and e_3) with the original dataset. This is my code thus far:

```
proc means data=unif;
    var e_2 e_3;
    output out=means (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_);
run;
```

Which gives a dataset named "means" like:

```
    _STAT_    e_2    e_3
1     N      50000  50000
2    MIN      0.2    0.4
3    MAX      0.8    0.9
4    MEAN     0.5    0.6
5    STD      0.1    0.2
```

From this "means" dataset, I need the mean and standard deviation of variables e_2 and e_3 to become variables of their own (4 variables total), so it ends of looking like this:

```
     mean_e_2    mean_e_3    sd_e_2   sd_e_3
1      0.5         0.6         0.1      0.2
```

I'm just looking to link up the means and standard deviations of e_2 and e_3 with my original dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Use the AUTONAME option in PROC MEANS/SUMMARY

```
proc summary data=test;
var e_2 e_3;
output out=means std= mean= /autoname;
run;
```

If you want to name each of the variables, try this

```
proc summary data=test;
var e_2 e_3;
output out=means std(e_2 e_3)=sd_e_2 sd_e_3 
                 mean(e_2 e_3)=mean_e_2 mean_e_3 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your input data using SASHELP.CLASS dataset. Let me know if the below reference codes helps.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class noprint;
 var age weight;
 output out=means (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_);
run;

proc transpose data=means out=means_transposed(keep=_name_ mean std);
 id _stat_;
 var age weight;
run;

data solution;
 merge means_transposed(where=(_name_='Age')    rename=(mean=mean_Age    std=std_Age   ))
       means_transposed(where=(_name_='Weight') rename=(mean=mean_Weight std=std_Weight))
      ;
  drop _name_;
run;
```

If you do not like TRANSPOSE that much or would rather want to keep things simple then the following code should help as well:

```
proc means data=sashelp.class noprint;
var age weight;
output out=means (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_);
run;

data solution;
do until(eof);
    set means end=eof;
        if _stat_='MEAN' then do; 
            mean_Age=age;
            mean_Weight=weight;
        end;
        else if _stat_='STD' then do; 
            std_Age=age;
            std_Weight=weight;
        end;
end;
keep mean_: std_:;
run;
proc print data=solution;run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the `ods output` method instead of the in-proc output.  The names are a bit longer which may be good or bad.

```
ods output summary=test;
  proc means data=sashelp.class mean stddev;
    var age weight;
  run;
ods output close;
```

I think that output organization is what you were looking for, but you can also add (9.3+ I believe) the `stackodsoutput` option to the `proc means` statement to get it with 1 row per variable, but the stats in the different columns (so the opposite of what you get from the automatic proc output).